# Unwanted Extra Text after modifying Social-share-button CSS in rails app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, font-awesome

Ok, I´m building an app and I'm using the `social-share-button`gem to display links to social sharing. I styled the look of the social share buttons and after that it's always displaying unwanted text below the icons ( see picture)

[image: Picture showing unwanted text]

In the `google developer tools` this is displaying like this ( see picture)

[image]

I'm totally blank on how to get rid of this "Share To"href="#">" text because it is not there in my code.

In the `categories/show.html.erb` I have this code

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row product_top">

    <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 center-block " >

    <%= link_to product_path (product) do %>
            <%= image_tag product.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive" %>
    <% end %>

    <div class="product_description">

      <h5><%= link_to product.title, product %></h5>
      <p><%= product.description %></p>
      <p class="price"> <%= number_to_currency(product.price_usd, :precision => 0) %></p>

       <p><%= social_share_button_tag(product.title) %></p> #This is were the problem is#

    </div>


  </div>
<% end %>
```

And here is the Css code in the `application.css.scss``

```
.social-share-button-facebook {
position: relative;
    background: none;
    margin-right: 5px;

 }

.social-share-button-facebook:before {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;

    content: "\f09a";
    color: #555;

    font-size: 1.5em;

}
```

After I customized the CSS this unwanted text is appearing.

**UPDATED**

here is the `config/initializers/social_share_button.rb`

```
SocialShareButton.configure do |config|
  config.allow_sites = %w(twitter facebook google_plus pinterest)
end
```

Have anyone experienced the same problem?
Can someone give my some help about this?

thanks in advance

D

Comment: can you show us the code for `social_share_button_tag` ? I'd be looking very strongly at the fact that it says `translation missing` in the html class section... are you relying on there being a class for various states of an object or something? Have you really double checked that the states all have a class? what do you do to check this?

Comment: I´m not sure how to check this, I´m really unexperienced in this but I have used this gem before with out any problems, but then this is the first time I've modified the CSS

Comment: what values do you expect to be coming out of `product.title` ?

Comment: I want to the user to be able to share the product on social media, showing picture and the title

Comment: I got rid of the unwanted text, somehow I forgot to run `rails generate social_share_button:install` at the begining, so the text is gone now but I can´t share anything

Answer (score 1):

Ok Ok the joke is on me :)

There were two problems that had to be solved...

first I had to run `rails generate social_share_button:install` that made the unwanted text disappear.

and the second one was to add `//= require social-share-button`to the `assets/javascript/application.js`

now this is working